# WPF ContextMenu fragment when collapses

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a context menu I want to appear when I activate context-menu-support and not to appear when context-menu-support is deactivated.

Therefor I have this context-menu applied to a button:

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Name="MyContextMenu" Header="Load To Stack" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <MenuItem Name="item0" Header="Stack 1" IsCheckable="False" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Name="item1" Header="Stack 2" IsCheckable="False" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Name="item2" Header="Stack 3" IsCheckable="False" Clic="MenuItem_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Name="item3" Header="Stack 4" IsCheckable="False" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</Button.ContextMenu>
```

I set the visibility of the Main-Context-Menu-Item by this function:

```
public bool ContextMode
    {
        get { return StackMode; }
        set 
        {
            if (value)
                MyContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            else
                MyContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

If the Visibility is Collapsed stays this fragment:
 [image]

I also tried to deactivate the entire context menu, but that doesn't work.
Is the context-menu deactivated and I try to let it popup the context menu doesn't show up.
If I activate the context-menu after I tried to get the deactivated c-m, two menu's are shown.

Maybe anyone knows how to get rid of the fragment shown.

Comment: Can you explain _I also tried to deactivate the entire context menu, but that doesn't work. Is the context-menu deactivated and I try to let it popup the context menu doesn't show up_? That is what is supposed to happen if you disable it. What are you trying to achieve here? Deactivate menu? Hide its content? What should be the outcome?

Comment: The ContextMenu should be invisible. To deactivate the context-menu works. But if you activate it, you'll get so many menus shown as how many times you tried to show the menu while it's deactivated. I just want to make it visible and invisible. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the `ContextMenuOpening` event of the *owning* `FrameworkElement`:

```
<Button Name="Button"
        Content="Test"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Padding="10"
        Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Name="Item0" Header="Load To Stack">
                <MenuItem Name="SubItem0" Header="Stack 1" IsCheckable="False"/>
                <MenuItem Name="SubItem1" Header="Stack 2" IsCheckable="False"/>
                <MenuItem Name="SubItem2" Header="Stack 3" IsCheckable="False"/>
                <MenuItem Name="SubItem3" Header="Stack 4" IsCheckable="False"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

And the code-behind:

```
private bool _contextMenuEnabled;

public MainWindow()
{
    _contextMenuEnabled = true;
    InitializeComponent();
    Button.ContextMenuOpening += Button_ContextMenuOpening;
}

void Button_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !_contextMenuEnabled;
}

private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _contextMenuEnabled = !_contextMenuEnabled;
}
```

Comment: It's fine if it's collapsed. But if I try to get the context-menu while it's collapsed, the menu appears twice if I activate the menu.

Comment: This is it, works as it should. I'd never thought that it's about the opening-event.